# Isn't it misleading for Scala 3 to claim it has dependent function types?

Tags: calculus-of-constructions

I am learning Scala 3 and so far I am really enjoying it. I was going through its [reference documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/index.html) and I noticed that it claims to have [dependent function types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/dependent-function-types.html). This feels misleading to me because the terminology "dependent function type" is more commonly associated with Π-types ([Calculus of Constructions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+constructions), [Pure Type Systems](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+type+system)) whereas Scala's dependent function types seem to be just plain old return-type polymorphism.

The reference documentation presents the following example:

```
trait Entry { type Key; val key: Key }

def extractKey(e: Entry): e.Key = e.key          // a dependent method

val extractor: (e: Entry) => e.Key = extractKey  // a dependent function value
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//             a dependent function type
```

In this example, the type of `def extractKey` could be rewritten as `def extractKey[E: Entry](e: E): E.Key = e.key`: the dependency on `e` is artificial since the value itself is not mentioned in the return type of `extractKey` in any way other than as a path to the concrete type that was abstracted away by the trait.

Am I off base here or does this "Scala 3 has dependent function types" claim sound fishy?

Comment: "Could be rewritten as" is true for a lot of things. What does of a list of `Entry`s look like if you re-write it?

Comment: @cody If Scala's "dependent function types" were really dependent then appending [this class](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VbMgJvzFTKiuyhUvPboHvQ) to the previous example should have been able to compile, no? This fails even before type checking, it fails at parsing.

Comment: Scala 3 doesn't have full dependent types, but only *path dependent types*, which is a weaker form of dependency. They allow values (e.g. objects) to carry types along with them, and these types can be used in type-checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my interpretation of how Scala types can be translated to type theory,
a trait is a type and an instance of the trait is a subtype. Therefore, in the example above, `Entry` would be:
$$\mathit{Entry} = \Sigma\mathit{Key} : *. \mathit{Key}$$
Notice that this is a dependent sum type (or existential, if you prefer); the first element (`Key`) is a type  and the second (`key`) is a value of this type.

Then, the `extractKey` method would be translated to:
$$
\mathrm{extractKey} :: \Pi e : \mathit{Entry}. \mathrm{fst}(e) \\
\mathrm{extractKey} = \lambda e : \mathit{Entry}. \mathrm{snd}(e)
$$
As I see it, this is indeed a dependent function.

This translation relies on subtyping for passing instances of the trait $\mathit{Entry}$ to this function. For example, if $E \sqsubseteq \mathit{Entry}$ is a class "extending" the trait (I hope I'm correctly using Scala terminology here), then a value $e :: E$ would also have the type $e :: \mathit{Entry}$ and could be passed to $\mathrm{extractKey}$.

If you want to make this subtype polymorphism more explicit, as I believe was your intention in the question, then it would be:
$$
\mathrm{extractKey} :: \forall E \sqsubseteq \mathit{Entry}. \Pi e : E. \mathrm{fst}(e) \\
\mathrm{extractKey} = \Lambda E \sqsubseteq \mathit{Entry}. \lambda e : E. \mathrm{snd}(e)
$$
and again you'd have a dependent function.